# How to run linux VM on MacOS with Vagrant and QEMU?

Tags: macos, vagrant, qemu, libvirt

Can anyone advise me how to run a headless linux (x86_64) virtual machine on a MacOS Monterey (Intel) using QEMU with HVF?
So far I have installed the **libvirt** and **qemu** with homebrew, also **vagrant-libvirt plugin**. I did not configure anything else and I am confused.

```
$ vagrant init centos/7
$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'centos' up with 'libvirt' provider...
Error while connecting to Libvirt: Error making a connection to libvirt URI qemu:///system:
Call to virConnectOpen failed: Failed to connect socket to '/usr/local/var/run/libvirt/virtqemud-sock': No such file or directory
```

Thanks for any help.

**Update**:
I am using [finch](https://github.com/runfinch/finch) now.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue. Did you manage to find a workaround @Kirill ?

Comment: @JamesMurphy As a workaround, I'm currently using [lima](https://github.com/lima-vm/lima), which I highly recommend.

Comment: @Kirill Do you know whether or not I can Install Laravel Homestead on Lima???

Comment: @Pathros It makes no sense because of laravel/homestead is Vagrant box and can be used only with Vagrant.

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen this https://gitlab.com/libvirt/libvirt/-/issues/75
looks like we need to wait for someone to implement a network driver that will actually work

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1131541)

Comment: Yes, you are right, it really is.
You can also find more information [here](https://github.com/vagrant-libvirt/vagrant-libvirt/issues/1017).